# How to prevent a Flash <embed> from being focused?

Tags: flash, focus

I'm working on a web page in which I have a non-interactive `.swf` Flash file in an `<embed>`. If the user clicks/scrolls inside the Flash, it gets focus, and starts capturing keyboard events like `F12` or `ctrl-R`. The content isn't interactive, just a fixed graphic. How can I prevent it from gaining focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `onfocus` event listener that blurs the element. Example, where `e` is the `<embed>` element:

```
e.onfocus = function() {e.blur()}; // unfocus it as soon as it's focused
```

Tested and works like a charm. Clicking on the Flash doesn't steal keyboard input.